# TDD List Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tdd

I understand the principal of TDD is to first write a test, watch it fail (or assume it will fail since there's no code yet), write a method, and then watch the test pass as it will use your new method.

I see how this works obviously if your method returns boolean or integer or some other data type which can be used with any of the following:

```
Assert.AreEqual();
Assert.IsNotNull();
Assert.IsTrue();
Assert.IsFalse();
etc.
```

But, often the functionality that I build is a method that returns a List of some type like this:

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  // return list of employees
}
```

How would I write a TDD test for this before hand (or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?)  I am obviously new to TDD (and I don't really see any inherent value in it, as of yet).

Comment: first test would be returns null.  second test would be empty list. etc.  However, I think that your problem is most likely using `static` not the fact that you are returning  a list. :)

Comment: 1. You're saying I should create multiple tests?  2.  Why shouldn't I use `static`?  Thanks.

Comment: 1. For simple tests it is enough to have just one method. But write at least meaningfull failure message into each assert. 2. The first reason to not use static members - it is not in OOP meaning. The member doesn't belongs to any instances, but only for one CLASS. The second reason - If you do further more complex TDD with mocking, you will see that static not virtual members are hard to mock or replace their values for test purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to test-drive the development of this method (I'm removing static):

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  // return list of employees
}
```

So, what's the minimum we can do?

```
public void ShouldReturnEmptyList() {
    List<Employee> list = new MyClass().GetEmployees();
    assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
}
```

OK, that's easy enough to make pass, right?

Now let's try to populate the list:

```
public void ShouldReturnListWithFred() {
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    Employee fred = new Employee("fred");
    c.addEmployee(fred);
    List<Employee> list = c.GetEmployees();
    assertTrue(list.contains(fred));
}
```

And you're pretty much done.  You can explore exceptional cases as well, of course, make assertions about the ordering, etc., but basically that's how you test-drive development of a list-returning method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as it helps me understand what I need to do/ why I do it.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 This is not correct. The test case `ShouldReturnEmptyList()` will fail as soon as you begin populating the list. In TDD, if you construct your test cases properly (this is a skill that takes some practice to become proficient in), you never go back to remove or change a previous test case. See my answer below.

Comment: @KeithPayne I see.  Either way, it's helps me understand.  Thanks for your critical point.

Comment: And to highlight the point about it being a skill, my answer actually breaks this rule too. Shows what happens when you don't pay close attention!

Answer (score 3):

To make TDD work as intended, you start from the simplest aspect of the unit under test.

Your first test ought to be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetEmployeesReturnsAList()
{
    List<Employee> result = MyClass.GetEmployees();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

And implement like so:

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  return new List<Employee>();
}
```

Now this test should fail before you add the code to return the list, and from then on never fail again through all of the refactoring and adding of code to the unit under test.

The next test would be something like:

> // This test is WRONG!! It is missing the setup of the available
>   employees
>
> My intent was to highlight that returning 1 employee is a simpler case
>   than returning the particular employee that is expected. Make sure to
>   start with the simpler case.
>
> //    [TestMethod] //    public void
>   GetEmployeesReturnsOneEmployeeWhenThereIsOneEmployeeAvailable() //
>   { //        List result = MyClass.GetEmployees(); //
>   Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count); //    }
>
> //

Run and the test fails. Then refactor like so:

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
    empList.Add(emp);

    return empList;
}
```

And now the test passes.

Next test might be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetEmployeesReturns_The_OneEmployeeWhenThereIsOneEmployeeAvailable()
{
    // Arrange

    Employee emp = new Employee();

    // Add code here to insert emp into the source of the list
    // This may be a mock.

    // Action
    List<Employee> result = MyClass.GetEmployees();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
    Assert.AreSame(emp, result[0]);
}
```

And now you add and re-write the code to make it pass without breaking any of the previous unit tests.

Rinse and repeat, adding the least amount of code possible to make the tests pass without breaking any other tests. You will have to re-write the code many times, but the result is that you get the simplest code possible that satisfies all of your tests. And if the requirements are completely represented by all of your tests, you now have a fully functional unit.

The key with TDD is that it prevents unnecessary complexity which usually comes about from making your code more abstract than it needs to be or before you discover a need for the complexity. You can always go in after-the-fact to make the code more abstract when a need is there. Note that a legitimate need may even be to satisfy code analysis tools.

But you are free to re-factor without fear because you have great test coverage.

One more thing with TDD is that you may want to augment these tests with technical edge case tests (passing null arguments and testing for the proper exception). However, this is not necessary and this is another benefit of TDD.

It highlights things that many developers think of as a "best practices", such as checking method arguments for null inside the method when those checks are not necessary because the calling code should never pass in a null. And if the calling code does pass a null, the problem lies with it and not with the code inside the method.

If there is a real code path that allows a null, and your method does not expect a null, then the calling code must perform the null check itself and do something other than call your method.

Comment: Could TDD ever be consider of as "training wheels" in that if you are a developer that does check for nulls and does not over-architect code, could this be more of a hindrance than a benefit?  I learned MVC because the benefits were obvious - separation of concerns.  But with this I am still struggling to find the benefit.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: TDD is not always appropriate. For instance, if you are working on a team and not all developers practice TDD then it is pretty much useless. Also, if you need code quickly that is functional but not necessarily easy to maintain, then is not helpful. And a big case when it is not helpful is when there is no overall design (yet).

Comment: Making the code easier to maintain would be a great benefit; however, I don't see how TDD helps with that.  Maybe I have to look at more examples...

Comment: But I wouldn't consider it training wheels. Even after using TDD a lot, I still find myself over abstracting during the times when I don't use it. So if it is supposed to lead to better code without the training wheels, it hasn't worked in my case!

Comment: TDD makes it easier for other people to maintain your code. Or for you to maintain your code 5 years and many projects from now.

Comment: Plus the test coverage that you get with TDD makes it easier to change other parts of the system without inadvertently breaking this part.

Answer (score 2):

To assert a collection, you can use [CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx).

Usually, to TDD a function, I'd like to

1. a simple happy path scenario, like return only 1 element.
2. a simple exceptional scenario, like return nothing, or throws exception.
3. a happy path, it will returns more than 1 element.
4. a more complex path, returns a filter result out from all the elements.

BTW, if you want to make your function unit-testable, avoid static or any global state or communication with I/O, Database, etc. (You might want to mock these real-world object)

Also, it will be easier to write test if all outside-function state is passed in by parameters rather than class fields(neither static or not).

Comment: I am a little confused by the "happy path" stuff.  Would it be possible for you to write an example test given my example function?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions). Has lots of collection assertions [HowTo – NUnit – Fluent Assertions](http://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-nunit-fluent-assertions/). You can use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq) for object mocking.

```
    private Mock<IActivityRepository> _mockActivityRepository;
    private Activity _expectedActivity = new Activity { Name = Name, Description = Details };

    /// <summary>
    /// Created by: kayz1
    /// Created: 23 jun 2011 23:48
    /// </summary>
    [Test, Description("GetAllActivities")]
    public void GetAllActivities_ValidProjects_ReturnProjects()
    {
        // Arrange
        var activities = new List<Activity> { _expectedActivity };
        _mockActivityRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAllActivities()).Returns(activities);
        // Act
        var resultList = _acitivityViewModel.GetAllActivities();
        // Assert
        _mockActivityRepository.VerifyAll();
        resultList.Should().HaveCount(1);
    }
```